# Is it possible to combine two sentences structured like this: if A then B. if no A then no B

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, redundancy

The following two sentences seem redundant. How do I combine them into a single sentence?

> Shortcomings are actually valuable opportunities that enable you to explore your potentials.
> Without shortcomings, you may not be able to find these valuable opportunities.

Comment: You might want to reword your question - the answer is yes, but what does that actually do for you?

Comment: Could you please reword it for me? I want it to look more concise.

Comment: The first sentence is not great. You're better off with a clause: that enable you to explore your potential. Also, stay away from "one", in most cases.

Comment: May I ask why not using "one" in most cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, one can express this two-way implication by *if and only if* (shortened in mathematics to *iff*).  But in this case it presents two problems:

1. It requires a restructuring that is less elegant than the original.
2. It changes "may not" into an absolute "cannot".

> One's potentials can be deeply explored, if and only if one discovers shortcomings that create the opportunities to do so.

I don't think you'll find a phrase that can accurately express "if A then B; if not A then perhaps not B".  I think your original sentences are fine, and could just benefit from removal of the obvious redundancy:

> Shortcomings are actually valuable opportunities to explore deep into one's potentials. Without shortcomings, one may not be able to find those opportunities.

Comment: Can I rephrase this sentence as ```Shortcomings are actually valuable opportunities to explore deep into one's potentials, without which, one may not be able to find those opportunities```?